# Flatlist getItemLayout usecase

Tags: android, performance, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Why we use getItemLayout in flatlist ,how it help to improve performance of a flatlist .check the react-native docs but didn't find a satisfying answer.

```
  getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
    {length: ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index, index}
  )}
```

what is offset here ,what it does?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

React Native FlatList optimises list view performance by only rendering rows that are currently visible on the screen, and unmounting rows that have been scrolled past.

In order for FlatList to be able to do this, it needs to know the total height of the rows above the currently visible viewport, so it can set the underlying ScrollView scroll position correctly.

There are two ways for FlatList to achieve this. Either,

- it can calculate the heights of the rows after the rows have been mounted, or
- you can tell it how tall you expect the rows to be.

In the former case, it needs to to fully layout, render, mount and measure the previous rows need until it is able to calculate the position of the next rows.

In the latter, it can precalculate the positions ahead of time and avoid the dynamic measurement cost.

The three arguments to the `getItemLayout` callback are:

- `length`: Height of each individual row. They can be of different heights, but the height should be static. The optimizations work best when the height is constant.
- `offset`: The distance (in pixels) of the current row from the top of the FlatList. The easiest way to calculate this for constant height rows is `height * index`, which yields the position immediately after the previous row.
- `index`: The current row index.

If the FlatList is horizontal, the each column is treated list a list row, and the column width is the same as row height.

Comment: If horizontal prop is true ,then height becomes width of item ,and row becomes column, in your answer???

Comment: Correct. Editing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: If I have an ItemSepearator on my FlatList, will `{ length: ItemHeight, offset: (ItemHeight + SeparatorHeight) * index, index}` be correct to use?

Comment: Should we include margins, padding of a item while using getItemLayout?

Comment: @jevakallio Does the item height include padding and margin? or should offset have those?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal Yes, YOU HAVE TO include ItemSeparator but not margin or paddings.

Comment: But after setting the getItemLayout props it comes reverted after loading some element.

Answer (score 8):

Even though @jevakallio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682288/12719767) is good for a vertical flatlist i faced some difficulties with margins when i implementing a horizontal flatlist so i'm writing this answer for someone who implements a similar thing

---

### ANSWER FOR A HORIZONTAL FLATLIST

i implemented a calendar in a horizontal flatlist and i wanted to show the current day when it first renders ( because then users don't have to scroll every time they use the calendar)

[image]

Here each day(item) is 60px width 70px height and also i'm giving a 10px horizontalMargin

```
item:{
  width: 60px,
  height: 70px,
  horizontalMargin: 10px
}
```

This is what you should do in your `getItemLayout`

1. **use width for length property**
2. **you should also add margin because it's `horizontal` flatlist**

```
      <FlatList
        data={daysOfThisMonth}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <RenderItemDays
            item={item}
            index={index}
            dayIndex={dayIndex}
            setDayIndex={setDayIndex}
          />
        )}
        initialScrollIndex={new Date().getDate() - 1} 
        getItemLayout={(_, index) => ({
          length: 60 + 20, //  WIDTH + (MARGIN_HORIZONTAL * 2)
          offset: (60 + 20) * (index),  //  ( WIDTH + (MARGIN_HORIZONTAL*2) ) * (index)
          index,
        })}
      />
```

---

If you don't understand my above answer [HERE](https://github.com/Sven2219/FlatlistGetItemLayout/blob/master/App.js) you can see a more detailed explanation

Comment: Thanks for noting that extra margins are required in the calculations between objects. Thats what I was looking for. I want to add though that you should probably remove those inline functions there, and instead move them into a single function above (ideally with useCallback).  It's not always necessary, but since this is a discussion about optimization I figure it would be helpful.

Comment: @Maxwell hi this is why i post answers so i can improve myself too ,   can u tell where is that inline function? is that the one on the initialScrollIndex prop?

Comment: Your renderItem prop and your getItemLayout prop are both using inline functions. It's funny cause that's how the official documentation writes it in their examples. Everyone suggets though to take those out into a single function (one for each prop) that uses useCallback. Therefore you aren't creating a new function for each individual item in your list. The performance increase is very significant.

Comment: @Maxwell i wasn't aware of this info, i'll do profiling before this optimization and update this answer and i think official docs try to be friendly as possible to beginners since including useCallback increase the code complexity... anyway thanks

Comment: Why getItemLayout needs index when that is the argument itself?