# FlatList hangs UI if uses initialNumToRender for larger value

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have created contact screen where on the right side there is a alphabatic dictionary character, if user select any of the character I need to move the flat list to that contact.

But previously I fount it was not working because flatlist didn't load all the data in the start and if i tried to move to that data which is not loaded by flatlist nothings happen.

SO for the time being i found out the solution with initialNumToRender internal method in which I send total count, it working but as My records are around 200 it gets hanged and take time between switching

Is there any better way to achieve the same ?

I used the flatList like this

```
<FlatList
        ref={ref => (this._mainList = ref)}
        initialNumToRender={this.props.data.length}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
        extraData={this.props.data}
        getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
        getItemLayout={this.props.getItemLayout}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        {...this.props}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

As already written here: [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

> initialNumToRender : This should be enough to fill the screen but not much more.

Comment: but it hangs as my records are 200 and I send 200 in this param, its takes time to render the flatlist

Comment: 200 is large data my friend, easy way out is to implement load more functionality be rendering 10 to 20 items first then show another data on scroll

Comment: hmm yeah but according to my functionality I need to show data according to the alphabet selected by user, is there any possible way ? Do you know how country listing library managing this when we select the letter in the right column ?

Comment: Try remoing initialNumToRender , getItemLayout and use keyExtractor as keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement getItemLayout? It helps the FlatList calculate where the items past initialNumToRender should be rendered. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682288/10236907) explains it pretty well.

Comment: I have used the getItemLayout function, 200 is a large value for initialNumToRender and it takes time to load the component is there any other possible way ?