# getItemLayout doing nothing to flatlists

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to optimize a FlatList with getItemLayout, but the getItemLayout prop is not doing anything. I can pass any value for length offset and index, and it will have no effect on the layout of the list. Consistently does nothing on both iOS simulator and Android emulator
React Native version 0.69.6

```
<FlatList
    data={list}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl
        onRefresh={() => null}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        colors={[COLOR.white]}
        tintColor={COLOR.white}
      />
    }
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({ length: 10, offset: 10 * index, index })}
    initialNumToRender={20}
  />
```

I have tried using this function in many different contexts and it never has any effect on the layout or performance of my flatlist.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of `getItemLayout` is NOT supposed to be seen visually. Its purpose is to speed up the calculation of the position of each list element. If `getItemLayout` is not supplied, the position of a list element cannot be calculated until all the previous items have been rendered. However, with `getItemLayout`, react native already knows the length (height for vertical list, width for horizontal) of each element, so it can quickly computes the position of every element. For more details, refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682288/9723036).

Therefore, supplying `getItemLayout` will not have any effect on how the rendered list looks like. But what it WILL affect is actions that require computation of an element position, such as the `initialScrollIndex` prop. You can try it out on [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@fanchenbao/effect-of-getitemlayout) (choose iOS or Android, toggle the value of `ITEM_HEIGHT` between 10 and 200, and wait for the app to re-render).

Note that in the example above, the height of each list element is set to 200. If `length` in `getItemLayout` is set to 10, when we tell `FlatList` to scroll to index 4 initially, it barely scrolls past the first element. Why? Because according to `getItemLayout`, to scroll to index 4 means to scroll to position 4 * 10 = 40, and that is well within the first element. So scrolling stops inside the first element.

To solve this problem, we must match `length` to the actual height (width) of the list element. In the example, we need to set `length` to 200, and the initial scroll would work.