# React Native FlatListProps.getItemLayout do not load more items

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I am working with a large list in React native, I using FlatList to show it.

But when I use getItemLayout to improve performance, the list doesn't load more elements behind.

If I remove the getItemLayout then FlatList still works as usual.

I am using React Native `0.66.5`.

This is [Snack Expo Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@ngvcanh/flatlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
offset: (data?.length ?? 0) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
```

to this

```
offset: idx * ITEM_HEIGHT,
```

`offset` indicates the distance from the top of the list to the element to be rendered. Its value should be dependent on the index of the element. It does not make sense to set this value to `(data?.length ?? 0) * ITEM_HEIGHT` for all the list elements.

Refer to the usage on [the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout). And check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682288/9723036) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seem I was a bit confused while reading the documentation and the performance tutorial blog.

Comment: I agree. The documentation can definitely use more clarification. If [this](https://dev.to/erdenezayaa/react-native-optimizing-flatlist-performance-31k) is the tutorial you are referring to, I have left a comment there to notify the error in the `offset`.